# How to persist changes to Glassfish properties in Netbeans (v8)

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I don't use the Derby database in Glassfish, and I don't want it to be automatically started when Glassfish starts.

In **Netbeans (v8)** `Services --> Servers --> Glassfish Server --> Properties --> Common`

I turn off the "Start Registered Derby Server" flag -- which works for the current session of Netbeans, only; the next time I start Netbeans, the flag is turned back on.  How do I make the settings persist across Netbeans sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that NetBeans is not persisting the change to the "Start Registered Derby Server" flag made from the GUI, to the `.nbattrs` file.  I was able to keep Derby from starting automatically as follows:

1. Exit NetBeans.
2. Edit `~/.netbeans/8.0/config/GlassFishEE6/Instances/.nbattrs`.
3. Find the `<fileobject>` element corresponding to the Glassfish server entry in the NetBeans "servers" tab for which Derby should not be started.
4. Change the `"derbyStartOn"` attribute to `"false"`.
5. Save the file
6. Start NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the solution - I applied it to Windows 8 on below path - wish I was able to up-vote it:

~\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GlassFishEE6\Instances