# Netbeans 8 and Glassfish 4 with @ServerEndpoint("/endpoint") - java source code changes are not (hot) deployed

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

A websocket with @ServerEndpoint("/endpoint") (Omitted originally - pardon)
 Source code changes are not (hot) deployed even though Glassfish report "LibV7 was successfully deployed in 660 milliseconds.".

Your kind advice will be much appreciated

(a servlet  @WebServlet(name = "Router", urlPatterns = {"/Router"}) hot deploys perfectly)

A follow-up - I migrated from Glassfish 4 to Tomcat 8 which works perfectly and meets my expectations

In desperation I applied the following change as per URL below and now Glassfish deploys compiled code correctly.

[How to persist changes to Glassfish properties in Netbeans (v8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797403/how-to-persist-changes-to-glassfish-properties-in-netbeans-v8?rq=1)

There is a user interface under servers to set / unset auto deployment for Derby - which does not work!!!